# How can I produce a count on the number of times each word has occurred in the following

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using the code below in Jupyter notebook, I can only produce a count of each character found. But I am looking to get a count on the number of times each word occurs.
Thank you!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup, Tag
import re
import requests
from collections import Counter

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_27"
DayBorn = [] # create a list to save the soup contents 
response = requests.get(url)
soup = Soup(response.content)


births_span = soup.find("span", {"id": "Births"}) # find where the first instance of span with ID of births appears
births_ul = births_span.parent.find_next_sibling() # find the parents next sibling which is ul (unordered list)

for item in births_ul.findAll('li'): # find all the occurrences of li within births_ul
    if isinstance(item, Tag): 
        #print(item.text) # if the next item found is a 'li' then print the value of its text
        DayBorn.append(item.text)
```

This next section gives me a list of each word as it occurs.

```
text_iterated = str(DayBorn) 
[x for x,y in re.findall(r'((\w+[^,.()]))', text_iterated)]
```

I have tried both these methods so far

```
Counter(str(text_iterated))
```

and

```
occurrences = Counter()
for word in str(DayBorn):
    occurrences[word] += 1
occurrences
```

They result in the same thing, a count of each number/letter
e.g.

```
counter({'[': 4,
         "'": 449,
         '8': 104,
         '9': 277,
         '2': 109,
         ' ': 2237,
         '–': 225,
         'E': 50,
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very specifically told your program to iterate through the characters of the list you created:

```
for word in str(DayBorn):
```

You converted the list to its string-output form, and then iterated through the characters of that string.  Instead,

```
for word in DayBorn:
```

Better yet, simply use the provided Python facility for counting:

```
from collections import Counter
...
occurrences = Counter(DayBorn)
```

---

EDIT per USER COMMENT

DayBorn needs to be a list of words.  Again, we need your MVE.  Perhaps this will help as you ingest lines: instead of adding the entire line to your list

```
    DayBorn.append(item.text)
```

... add the words individually

```
    DayBorn.extend(item.text.split())
```

Comment: Hi Prune and thanks for this help. Do you mean remove the section after the 'and', then replace it with 'occurrencies = Counter(DayBorn)' ?

Comment: Yes; those four lines are incorrect; doing the counting is that one line of code.  If you have further difficulties, please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Much of the problem in answering your post is that your question is incomplete.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the result is that each line is counted rather than each word. e.g. Counter({'892 – Emperor Ai of Tang, Chinese emperor (d. 908)': 1,
                                '921 – Chai Rong, Chinese emperor (d. 959)': 1,
I will do some more research and follow up on the advice given.

Comment: Thanks Prune! I solved it myself too by using Word_count = Counter(str(DayBorn).split()